# How to use windows nano server image for hosting my .net application

Tags: .net, docker, powershell, nano-server, windows-server-container

Installing Oracle Client and .NET Framework on Windows Nano Server LTSC 2022 for .NET Application Hosting

Background:
I have successfully hosted a .NET application on a Windows Server Core LTSC 2022, using the Oracle Client for database communication. However, the Server Core image has a large size (around 6 to 7 GB). Now, I am attempting to achieve the same on a Windows Nano Server LTSC 2022 to reduce the image size. The Nano Server does not have the traditional MSI installer, and installing PowerShell has proven challenging.

Steps Taken on Nano Server:

Base Image Used:
I am using the base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022.

PowerShell Installation Attempt:
I tried installing PowerShell using the installation file, but it failed due to the absence of misexec.exe on Nano Server.

WSA Package Installer Issue:
Nano Server does not have the traditional MSI installer and comes with WSA Package Installer. However, I couldn't find information on installing packages using WSA on Nano Server.

Copying MSI Installer Files:
I attempted to copy MSI installer files and binaries from a Windows Server 2022 system to Nano Server, but it did not work.

Docker Multistage Build Technique:
I employed the Docker multistage build technique, referencing servercore:ltsc2022 to create a core image. I installed PowerShell on this image and tried copying the files into Nano Server, but this approach also failed.

Key Questions:

How can I install PowerShell on Nano Server LTSC 2022, given the absence of traditional MSI installers?
What is the correct method for installing packages on Nano Server using the WSA Package Installer?
Are there alternative approaches or best practices for reducing the image size on Nano Server while maintaining the required components (Oracle Client, .NET Framework 4) for hosting the .NET application?
Note:
I am looking for a solution that does not involve using IIS on Nano Server, and I need to build the setup from scratch without relying on pre-configured Nano IIS server images.

below is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
SHELL ["powershell"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/download-powershell.msi -OutFile powershell.msi; \
   Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i', 'powershell.msi', '/quiet', '/norestart' -    NoNewWindow -Wait

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022

WORKDIR /NanoServer

COPY --from=0 /Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell /NanoServer/WindowsPowerShell

RUN cmd /S /C "setx PATH \"%PATH%;C:\NanoServer\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\""

WORKDIR /app
```

This also did'not work

could any one please help me on this .

Comment: What errors are you getting?  You have a Frontend connection between the client and server using powershell and a Backend connection between the server and nano server which is docker.  Determine if your errors are in the Frontend or Backend.  See following to resolve Docker/PS errors in the Backend : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/powershell-in-docker?view=powershell-7.4

Comment: I want to install powershell and .net3 iis feature on windows nano server container , if it possible then I can do the rest . There is no error message in docker . I just type powershell on the container after it's builds it does'nt give any response . And I enter this command for checking which tool is using : echo %COMSPEC% , it gives C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe . this means it still executing commands in cmd.exe not in powershell .

Comment: I had enter powershell from the folder which I copied from servercore but it is giving an empty result . eg: C:/NanoServer/windowsPowe4rshell/v01/powershell.exe 
C:/NanoServer/windowsPowe4rshell/v01/

Comment: We have to understand why you are not getting a response. No response usually means that the connection did not complete, but could also mean an unhandled exception occurred which the request was being processed. With a IIS both can occur.  IIS is an Older OS that does not handle the newer TLS encryption methods. So often with IIS the connection never completed when a unsupported encryption mode is used and you do not get a response. IIS is very secure and does not allow most connections (GUEST account) to access the System Resources like the Filesystem which can create unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Yeah , I think copy pasting of PowerShell utilities is not enough to run the PowerShell tool.